# Increase Ubuntu partition

Tags: partitioning

I have a sony vaio laptop on which both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 are installed.
When I installed Ubuntu on pre-existing Windows, I gave it a partition size of 15GB.
Now as softwares requires more space I want to increase it to 20GB.
I even have unallocated space of 9GB so that is not the problem, but I'm unable to do so using Gparted.
No matter how many times I have tried it does not increase past 14363MB.

[image]

Comment: **Backup all you data first**. Data disaster could be happened anytime.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you don't have that unallocated space right after the `/dev/sda7`. In one step you can only enlarge a partition when unallocated space goes right after a partition. Bout you can do in multiple steps: moving partitions boundaries from right to left one by one. **Note: Backup you precious data**

You better remove `swap` in `/dev/sda6` - for this boot up your machine from Live CD.

- Boot from Live CD
- Run `Gparted`
- Delete `swap` = `/dev/sda6`
- Move `/dev/sda7` to the left. It will take a long time, because it's a copying itself, so probably one-two hours for 15Gigs.
- Resize `dev/sda7`

Done.